# I want Power BI DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, many-to-many, dax, measure

Hi My Transaction Table,

Transaction Table
User    Transaction Country Cost    To Region
A   AUD 100 Nok
A   CHF 200 EUR
A   DKK 300 EUR
A   EUR 400 EUR
B   AUD 400 DKK
B   CHF 500 DKK
B   DKK 600 DKK
B   EUR 600 GBB

[image]

Exchange rate Table,

Exchange Rate
Country Rate    Region  Date
AUD 4.73    DKK 28.02.2023
CHF 7.49    DKK 28.02.2023
DKK 1.00    DKK 28.02.2023
AUD 0.64    EUR 28.02.2023
CHF 1.01    EUR 28.02.2023
DKK 0.13    EUR 28.02.2023
AUD 0.56    GBP 28.02.2023
CHF 0.88    GBP 28.02.2023
DKK 0.12    GBP 28.02.2023
EUR 1.00    EUR 28.02.2023

[image]

My expected result

[image]

How do i achieve this in power bi dax

I have tried in power query editor merge but it didnt help as expected. i want this in power bi dax measure

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text along with expected results.

Comment: Transaction Table,
User Transaction Country Cost  To Region
A AUD 100 Nok
A CHF 200 EUR
A DKK 300 EUR
A EUR 400 EUR
B AUD 400 DKK
B CHF 500 DKK
B DKK 600 DKK
B EUR 600 GBB

Exchange Rate   
Country Rate Region Date
AUD 4.73 DKK 28.02.2023
CHF 7.49 DKK 28.02.2023
DKK 1.00 DKK 28.02.2023
AUD 0.64 EUR 28.02.2023
CHF 1.01 EUR 28.02.2023
DKK 0.13 EUR 28.02.2023
AUD 0.56 GBP 28.02.2023
CHF 0.88 GBP 28.02.2023
DKK 0.12 GBP 28.02.2023
EUR 1.00 EUR 28.02.2023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to each declare variables for Region and country then declare a variable to match the exchange rate, then return as per exchange rate variable.

Comment: Measure = 
VAR selectregion = SELECTEDVALUE('Exchange Rate'[Region])
var SelectCountry =SELECTEDVALUE   ('Transaction'[Transaction Country])
VAR ExchangeRate = CALCULATE(
SUM('Exchange Rate'[Rate]),'Exchange Rate'[Region] = selectregion && 'Exchange Rate'[Country]=SelectCountry)
RETURN
SUMX('Transaction', 'Transaction'[Cost] * ExchangeRate)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).